# ScrollView has ambiguous scrollable content height

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am making a very basic UIScrollView test. Here is my setup [image]  It shows me the following AutoLayout error:

```
ScrollView has ambiguous scrollable content height
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You need to ensure you've got a chain of vertical spacing constraints from the top of the scroll view through all your elements to the bottom of the scroll view.

Once you do that, your warning/error should go away.

Comment: I have given a height to the scrollview. Will it work? Or do i need to add bottom guide as well ?

Comment: @AbdulYasin, no, you need the content within the scrollview to have a defined height as well. The height of the content in the scrollview can be larger or smaller than the height of the scrollview itself.

Comment: But then how scrollView will scroll if we set if frame equal to its contentsize??

Comment: @Developer the scrollview's frame does not equal the size of the scrollview's content. If they were equal, then the scrollview would never scroll.